# Can we send Rich text Field's HTML from Service Cloud to any other system Via API

Tags: soap-api, integration, rest, servicecloud, richtextarea

We have a use case where the Users will make text entries in a Rich Text Salesforce Field and will do customization on the input text field with the salesforce provided rich field's capability. We need to send the HTML, that will be generated after the users make their input, from Service cloud to another System using API calls.

Is it possible to send the HTML generated from a rich text field in the Service cloud to any other third party system via REST or SOAP APIs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rich text field will store the whole value with html line breaks, bold, italics etc as text/string. So when you send this value in API, it just sends it as string. If the third party system has to display it, they can very well use this value as **innerHTML**

Answer (score 0):

Of course !

The field, even if it's a rich text, will expose the html content of the field

for exemple :

```
myRichText: "Hey folks! <br> This is a rich <b>text field value</b>"
```

You can try with Postman or Workbench to call standard APIs and get a rich text value from a Salesforce object :)